# JSXBundle not found

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, jsx

[image]

I've added ever Nuget package I can find and have followed a number of tutorials step by step.
I can't find any questions about what package supplies the JsxBundle functionality.
Also added and removed a large combination of React and Microsoft packages to make sure I wasn't missing something.
Looking for the specific nuget package to install for the JsxBundle, Using vs2019